# Acceleration on a system of two particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, laws-of-physics

Let's imagine we have a system of two particles. If we apply an external force to only one of the two particles where the external force is greater than the internal force, then due to internal forces, will both particles move with the same acceleration, similar to how they would be connected by a string, or will they both have different accelerations?

[image]

Comment: The answer to this question is always the same.  Draw a free-body diagram for each particle and write down Netwon's 2nd Law for each particle.  What does that tell you about the accelerations?

Comment: *...due to internal forces...* what internal forces?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Any internal forces between both particles which are equal in magnitude but opposite in direction

Comment: @Mathologist such as?

Comment: There are no internal forces in "particle".

Answer (score 2):

Define system.

The answer depends on how the two particles are connected. Is there a fixed positional constraint (like a massless rod) between them? Another option is a force connection (like gravity, or a spring).

You are asking in general what are the kinematics of a two-particle system, but there is no general answer. The kinematics (range of allowable motions) between the particles is something *you* need to define when you describe your system.

Comment: Oh, that's where I was confused, I thought that every particle in a system due to external and internal forces always acts in the same way, like I thought that the acceleration on both particles is always the same due to internal forces when an external force is applied (like when two particles are connected with a string) irrespective of how both particles are connected. This means that there is also such cases where due to external force both particles may accelerates differently or maybe only 1 particle accelerates, isn't it?

Comment: I was confused because I thought that when we pull or push a rigid body then whole particles inside the system accelerates with the same acceleration and similar result seen when the particles are connected with a string.

Comment: @Mathologist in Newtonian mechanics, to find acceleration of a body we treat it as a point mass- thus the total acceleration of all the constituent particles of the body has to be the same. These aren't 'internal forces', it's something more like the particles are glued together and have no choice but to move together. If I were to scatter them around a room, and apply a force on one of these scattered particles, it would only cause the acceleration of that particle.

Comment: @StutiGupta - I do not exactly agree with what you say. If you do take a rigid body with a multitude of point masses _with fixed distances between them_, then you can sum up all the contributions as the acceleration of a single point (the center of mass). This process is not automatic but due to systematic accounting of all internal forces that do exist.

Comment: @Mathologist - the solar system can be considered as a "system" and each planet as a point mass. The interactions between the planets are internal forces and do not involve a direct physical connection between them. Although a rigid body is a system, but so is an isolated volume of fluid, or a star system, or a galaxy. There are many types of "systems" each with their own laws of interaction between their contents.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, you're right, but OP wouldn't know what a centre of mass is and if nothing is mentioned, you can always assume the body to be a point mass.

Answer (score 1):

Internal forces are those forces which are applied on both the particles, of equal magnitudes and opposite directions.That being said, in answer to your query:it depends on what the forces are. The tension in a rod could be an internal force, which would indeed cause same acceleration of both particles. Gravitational force, on the other hand, would not be strong enough to cause equal acceleration of the particles. The point is, a lot depends on actually what these forces are (actually, their magnitudes), and whether they are enough to cause $any$ acceleration of the second mass or not, equal magnitude to that of first one set aside.
If they were to be connected by a string, however - you've already put a constraint there. A string, assumed inextensible, must not break or slack- this means that the accelerations of the two masses have to be same. If there's no string or a rod or anything binding them together, then the little gravitational force between is negligible and will not cause any acceleration of the second mass(to which no force is applied).